# Ultragrid header checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I got a ultragrid with a column "A" that has a checkbox. How can I know if on all my rows this column is checked? Because there is a general checkbox that can be used to alter the state of column "A" in all my rows by using CheckAll() function, so it has to be a way to know if all my rows have this column checked, right?

Thanks in advance.

Btw: I tried to use GetHeaderCheckedState function but as I have group by rows I need to use the GetAllNonGroupByRows() function that returns an array of UltraGridRow, and the GetHeaderCheckedState function only receives a RowsCollection... Is there some way to convert UltraGridRow[] to RowsCollection?

PS:I don't know if this makes some kind of difference but this is a non-web application in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario, you may be able to use either the `BeforeHeaderCheckStateChanged` or `AfterHeaderCheckStateChanged` event on the `UltraGrid`. This would allow you to use the `RowCollection` property on the incoming `EventArgs`. For example:

```
private void ultraGrid1_BeforeHeaderCheckStateChanged(object sender, BeforeHeaderCheckStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].GetHeaderCheckedState(e.Rows);
}
```

If this approach is not suitable for your scenario, you could use the parent rows. For example:

```
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].GetHeaderCheckedState(ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.ChildBands[0].Rows);
```